# Python Pandas - Transform dataframe into key (multi index) => value table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
current_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['honda crv', 9000, 9100, 9200],
        ['mazda cx5', 9300, 10000, 10100],
        ['mazda cx5', 29300, 310000, 510100],
    ],
    columns=['car', 'john', 'peter', 'kate']
)
```

How do I transform this into dataframe with multiple index ['car', 'salesman']?

From this

[image: Current dataframe]

To this

[image: Desired dataframe]

Comment: If a solution helped you, remember to accept that answer with the green checkmark. This both marks the question as solved and rewards the person who helped you.

Comment: As Nick was suggesting, accepting the proposed solution with the green checkmark (next to the arrows in the answer) helps in keeping the question clean and useful for others (rather than editing your post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame( current_df.set_index('car').stack() )
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Simons answer (which should be accepted), to also get the correct headers add the following.

```
current_df = (
    pd
    .DataFrame(current_df.set_index("car").stack())
    .rename(columns={0: "price"})
    .rename_axis(("car", "salesman"))
)
print(current_df)

                     price
car       salesman        
honda crv john        9000
          peter       9100
          kate        9200
mazda cx5 john        9300
          peter      10000
          kate       10100
          john       29300
          peter     310000
          kate      510100
```